# how do i make it so that instead of names already being in the array that the user has to input names into the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, random

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace namegenerator1._2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    { 
        string[] FirstNames = { "jan", "jaap", "sjuul", "koen" };
        
        Random rand = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int indexFirstName = rand.Next(FirstNames.Length);

            this.txtbox_FirstName.Text = FirstNames[indexFirstName];
        }
    }
}
```

This basically makes a little box that generates random names from the array. I need to make it so that before the user gets to that he needs to put in a bunch of names himself. Which I don't know how to do.

Comment: Consider using a `List<string>` rather than a `string[]`.  Lists are *stretchy*; as you add things (using the `Add` method), the list gets longer.  When you create the list, it has no items, every time you call `Add`, the number of items grows by one

Comment: Add a `TextBox` control to form and make it multiline (set `Multiline` to true). Then, you'll be able to use `textBox.Text.Split('\n')` as your source of `string[]`

Answer (score 0):

You either check the array length to see if there are enough games, or use list as suggested.

If the array.Length is not enough, either use Input box or TextBox to ask for user input.

The input will go in the array/list with list.Add or by rearranging the array